# Run sql script placed in docker volumen

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

In my docker-compose.yml I placed init.sql into volumen.

```
version: '3'
services:
    mysqldb:
        image: mysql:5.7.22
        container_name: mysql
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1-init.sql
```

I know that I should run this script via Dockerfile file. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [official Docker mysql image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) will run everything present in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` when the database is first initialized (see "Initializing a fresh instance" on that page).  Since you're injecting it into the container using a volume, if the database doesn't already exist, your script will be run automatically as you have it.

That page also suggests creating a custom Docker image.  The Dockerfile would be very short

```
FROM mysql:5.7.22
COPY init.sql /docker/entrypoint-initdb.d/1-init.sql
```

and then once you built the modified image you wouldn't need a copy of the script locally to have it run at first start.

Comment: When I build image I get the following error: 
`Step 2/2 : COPY init.sql /docker/entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
COPY failed: stat /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/tmp/docker-builder835919145/init.sql: no such file or directory`

Comment: I used another command to build image from Dockerfile, that's why I got this error. Finally it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run a init script every time you run the container, You could write it as below::

```
 services:
 mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    command: --init-file /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1-init.sql
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
    environment:
       - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
       - MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead
       - MYSQL_USER=root
       - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
    volumes:
       - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql`

        `
```

Comment: After command docker-compose. Container has status restarting only.